# Skaffold with minikube and local registry failed to get the image name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube, skaffold

Since I have upgraded helm, Skaffold and Minikube to the latest version, my local project has been failed to get deployed to minikube with the following warning:

```
Listing files to watch...
 - tect-cicd
Generating tags...
 - tect-cicd -> tect-cicd:2.2.19-5-gfb14eb3-dirty
Checking cache...
 - tect-cicd: Found Locally
Tags used in deployment:
 -tect-cicd -> tect-cicd:ce2c8b21a565fc96d3e2c8f9821e7a9b3364fe0c06bc4611d63e64c1332f43a3
   local images can't be referenced by digest. They are tagged and referenced by a unique ID instead
Starting deploy...
WARN[0003] image [tect-cicd:ce2c8b21a565fc96d3e2c8f9821e7a9b3364fe0c06bc4611d63e64c1332f43a3] is not used. 
WARN[0003] image [tect-cicd] is used instead.    
WARN[0003] See helm sample for how to replace image names with their actual tags: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/blob/master/examples/helm-deployment/skaffold.yaml 
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: "test-cicd" has no deployed releases
Cleaning up...
Error: unknown flag: --purge
FATA[0003] exiting dev mode because first deploy failed: deploying test-cicd: exit status 1
```

My skaffold.yml

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha1
kind: Config
profiles:
- name: dev
  activation:
  - kubeContext: minikube
    command: dev
  build:
    tagPolicy:
      gitCommit: {}
    artifacts:
    - image: tect-cicd
      jib:
        type: maven
        args:
        - -Dmaven.test.skip
        - clean
    local:
      push: false
  deploy:
    helm:
      releases:
      - name: test-cicd
        chartPath: deployment/helm
        setValues: # listing the env variables here for secrets according to secrets.yaml file
          secret.db.password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        valuesFiles:
        - deployment/helm/values/values-default.yaml
        - deployment/helm/values/secrets.yaml
        - deployment/helm/values/values-dev.yaml
```

I am not sure if I am missing something or this is just a bug I am hitting.

Comment: How did you update all of your components? From which to which version did upgrade took place?

Comment: @DawidKruk from ver 2 to 3.  There is a convert 2to3 helm plugin that I have used for this

Comment: Please take a look at: [Github issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3353#issuecomment-385222233) and let me know if it helped with any errors you get.

Comment: @Alin did you figure out the answer? I am facing this issue

Comment: @BilalAhmad Not really. There have been a lot of bugs with the new Helm. Sometimes it happens again. When I rename the deployment and pod it's fixed. I am not sure what exactly is causing this issue though

Comment: I had the similar issue. Doing following helped:


1. update helm, version to 3.2.1
2. While running skaffold dev, start passing --force=false